# Will I be able to have 3rd party payment system in my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an iOS app where users can ask for advice to influential people on their subject. In order to interact with these people you have to pay the price they set. Once you pay you are able to engage with them on a private chat.

There is an app called Healthtap which does almost the same but with doctors.

I wanted to know if we might be able to use paypal and stripe payment systems instead of apple's.

For more info, I'm building it with HTML5 and making it native with Phonegap

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You "have" to use apple's system when paying will add more content to the app, which seems to me, is what you are trying to do.

[From Apple's In-App Purchase Programs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> You should read this if you are interested in offering **additional
>   paid functionality** to users from within your application.

You can use other payment methods when you are not adding new functionality to the app but rather buy something else in the real world. This is the reason why apps such as Amazon's kindle stopped selling ebooks through their apps, since they did not want to share their profits with apple.

Answer (score -2):

No, Apple does not allow any third-party payment methods to be presented in the app itself; it's IAP or nothing.

What you CAN do is have the third-party payment system as part of your web site and have your users make payments through the web site.  You will then need some authentication system in the app that uses to validate the user's payment.

Comment: Not true. This is only the case when payment unlock feature or download digital asset to the application. Unlocking service or advice is another case.